# Is this reported sentence ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity

> A: Are you a politician?
>
> B: No, I'm not a politician.

When we report the B's reply as: *B replied negatively that he was not a politician.*, is the sentence ambiguous - whether B denied the fact that he *was not* a politician or he denied that he *was* a politician?

Comment: **A**: *Are you late?* **B**: *No, I'm not (late)*. **B** responds negatively to the question. The speaker's response is negative.

Comment: In the question, B did not "reply negatively", but "in the negative" – he denied that he was a politician. If B had replied "negatively" he might have said, perhaps, "I am not interested in such questions." There are two meanings of **negative** – antonyms of **affirmative** and **positive**.

Comment: @WeatherVane The Cambridge Dictionary gives "negatively" the meaning **in a way that expresses "no"**, and also cites the example: **When he applied for a loan, the bank replied negatively**.

Comment: Saying they replied "**in a way** that expresses no" is not synonymous with "the bank said no."